# Rails 4 Multithreaded App - ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, multithreading, activerecord

I have a simple rails app that scrapes JSON from a remote URL for each instance of a model (let's call it A).  The app then creates a new data-point under an associated model of the 1st.  Let's call this middle model B and the data point model C.  There's also a front end that let's users browse this data graphically/visually.

Thus the hierarchy is A has many -> B which has many -> C.  I scrape a URL for each A which returns a few instances of B with new Cs that have data for the respective B.

While attempting to test/scale this app I have encountered a problem where rails will stop processing, hang for a while, and finally throw a "ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds"  Obviously the 5 is just the default.

I can't understand why this is happening when 1) there are no DB calls being made explicitly, 2) the log doesn't show any under the hood DB calls happening when it does work 3) it works sometimes and not others.

What's going on with rails 4 AR and the connection pool?!

A couple of notes:

1. The general algorithm is to spawn a thread for each model A, scrape the data, create in memory new instances of model C, save all the C's in one transaction at the end.
2. Sometimes this works, other times it doesn't, i can't figure out what causes it to fail.  However, once it fails it seems to fail more and more.
3. I eager load all the model A's and B's to begin with.
4. I use a transaction at the end to insert all the newly created C instances.
5. I currently use resque and resque scheduler to do this work but I highly doubt they are the source of the problem as it persists even if I just do "rails runner Class.do_work"

Any suggestions and or thoughts greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have found the cause of this problem.  When you loop through an association via

```
model.association.each do |a|
   #work here
end
```

Rails does some behind the scenes work that "uses" a DB connection.  I put uses in quotes because in my case I think the result is actually returned from memory.  I eager loaded the association and thus the DB is never actually hit.

Preliminary testing of wrapping my block in a

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do 
#something me doing?
end
```

seems to have resolved the issue.

I uncovered this by adding a backtrace to my thread's error message that was printing out.

-----For those using resque----

I also had to add a bit in my resque.rake file to get this fully working as intended.

```
task 'resque:setup' => :environment do 
  Resque.after_fork do |job|
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are you using

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do 

    ... code

end
```

to accomplish faster transactions in a thread, note that this locks the database. I had an app that did this for a hugely expensive process, in a thread, and it would lock the DB for over 5 seconds. It is faster, though it will lock your database

Comment: Apologies for this late reply and thank you for your efforts.  However, I am not doing a transaction within each thread.  The flow of things is to eagerload all associations, spawn threads to gather data, then once all threads are done save all new info to DB in 1 transaction.

You may be on to something though, with the DB remaining locked longer than I initially expected.